# Python kernel crash in Jupyter Notebook when calling TSNE.fit_transform()

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

I have an output of `sklearn`'s `tf-idf` which I want to visualize with T-SNE. However, when calling `fit_transform` on `sklearn`'s `T-SNE` object, I get the error message:

> "Canceled future for execute_request message before replies were done

> The Kernel crashed while executing code in the the current cell or a
> previous cell. Please review the code in the cell(s) to identify a
> possible cause of the failure. Click here for more info. View Jupyter
> log for further details."

Why is this happening? Code below.

```
dense = np.array(
   [[0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
   [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
   [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
   [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
   [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 1.        , 0.        ],
   [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 1.        , 0.        ],
   [0.70710678, 0.70710678, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
   [0.        , 0.        , 0.70710678, 0.        , 0.70710678],
   [0.70710678, 0.70710678, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
   [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
   [0.        , 0.        , 0.70710678, 0.        , 0.70710678]])

from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
tsne = TSNE(n_components = 2, verbose = 1, perplexity = 50, n_iter = 1000)
results = tsne.fit_transform(dense)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't able to reproduce the error in a Google Colab. It works fine on my end, with the following output:

```
[t-SNE] Computing 10 nearest neighbors...
[t-SNE] Indexed 11 samples in 0.000s...
[t-SNE] Computed neighbors for 11 samples in 0.009s...
[t-SNE] Computed conditional probabilities for sample 11 / 11
[t-SNE] Mean sigma: 1125899906842624.000000
[t-SNE] KL divergence after 250 iterations with early exaggeration: 39.474655
[t-SNE] KL divergence after 1000 iterations: 0.268328
```

I've found an old [thread](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/4619) on GitHub that may address the problem. It is a Mac related issue, but I don't know what OS does your machine has.

There is a chance that they fixed the error in newer versions of sklearn, so my first suggestion is to try upgrading, if you haven't already.

If the issue still persists, since the problem may be due to a dependency that sklearn uses (and even if you do not have a Mac, you still have a problem), I would recommend using a different library. I know about [`python-bhtsne`](https://github.com/dominiek/python-bhtsne) that can be used in a similar way as sklearn's.

Comment: FWIW, I wasn't able to reproduce the error with a local instance of Jupyter, either (Windows 10, Jupyter 5.5.0 with Python 3.6.5)

Comment: My machine runs on Mac OS indeed. I have scikit-learn 1.02 installed. My environment can't be solved to allow for higher version of sklearn, but I'll try with a new environment.

Comment: I am still having the crash issue.

Comment: Have you tried getting the latest version of scikit-learn? @lighthouse